# Cannot start chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, windows-xp

Suddenly, I cannot start Google Chrome anymore. When I double click `chrome.exe`, it seems that nothing happens. I can see chrome.exe in the task manager after clicking `chrome.exe` , but after a moment , `chrome.exe` is closed automatically and nothing happen.(with error message)

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall but the problem is still there. I refer to [this thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1916f28bfce5a937&hl=en&start=80) to try to use `tdsskiller.exe` to check if there are any *rootkits* in my computer but still failed. Any idea?

My operating system is Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Is the chrome.exe process actually running? Check using Task Manager > Processes.

Comment: No , `chrome.exe` does not appear in the task manager .It does not load into the process

Comment: So it's not opening the window off screen then.

Comment: nothing happens , no window off screen pop up , just like i did not press `chrome.exe` , but actually , i did press it.

Comment: yes , i did try to uninstall and then reinstall chrome.

Comment: Are you using the dev or beta channel perhaps?

Comment: Right click on the chrome shortcut and select "open", any difference?

Comment: @Al Everett  : I am using the latest version download from google.com .It should be the release version @Moab : no difference , still cannot open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems is because my computer is infected by some Trojan or malware that modify some registry setting . It cannot open some type of .exe such as chrome.exe or even the opera installation file . I finally managed to detect and remove these Trojan /malware using a free software produced by a China company called 360

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're using a Beta version of Chrome and it just doesn't like something to do with your system. If you can figure out which version your running and make sure it isn't a beta, then you might be lucky.

If not, you could try opening it using your terminal and see if there is any relevant output that gets spit out at you.

If all else fails, my guess if some kind of virus. Anything else 'freaky' happening to your computer?

Comment: It is not the beta version as it is downloaded from  [link](http://www.google.com/chrome?hl=en) . I did try to open chrome.exe in the cmd.exe , but nothing happen.The chrome.exe is loaded in the task manager after I run chrome.exe , but after that , it is closed automatically and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling chrome then delete the folder in program files then install chrome. This should fix the problem

Comment: I tired this before but the chrome still cannot be opened

Comment: It is very possible that you have a virus or hijack software on your computer